# How can I download libraries from maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am working on a plugin on IntelliJ.

I am willing to make a project template in IntelliJ. And I want to be able to download library from the maven remote repositories and add the library into my project.

How can I do it in my plugin by code auto?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand correctly your question, so...

If you want to create a project with Maven which includes all of the libraries when you build the jar, take a look to the shade plugin.

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an
>   uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the
>   packages of some of the dependencies.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/